# BlockUI Messagebox height not as i want

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is there anyway I can display this only 1 message box **(out of 3)** a bit upper on screen then where it is now.

as I am adding a lot of controls to messagebox and it is out of visiblity in screen and I want to move it up.

I am using this,

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#dialog

I am not afraid of getting into plugin file and modify it sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even better, to avoid modifying the library (which is bad practice since you might want to update it one day and forget about your changes), use CSS:

```
.blockUI.blockMsg { top: 10% !important; }
```

anywhere in you page stylesheet.

Since these are added inline to the element, you need the `!important` part to get precedence.

Comment: Can I do with one specific message box sir ? as I got 3 different messaegbox and only want this style to apply to only one of them :(

Comment: after reading up on the library - you can actually define it per invocation using params - see relevant example in the [library documentation](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#demo4)

Comment: try this: `$.blockUI({ 
  message: $('#popup'), 
  css: { top: '10%' } 
});

Comment: cheers, can you tell me where did you find these properties in block ui please as I am not able to find "text-align" property and if I try this,  $('#popup'), css: { text-align: 'left' } }); it doesn't work, thankssssssss a lot

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523066/blockui-forces-all-elements-to-center

Answer (score 1):

On line 616:

```
top:            '40%',
```

Change that value to set another Y position.