# BlockUI forces all elements to center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blockui

How can I re-force my elements back to left align as jquery blockui plugin is forcing them to center,

I tried this so far,

```
$.blockUI({ message: $('#popup'), css: { text-align: 'left' } });
```

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos

Comment: can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: I think with out putting text-align left it will work like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use camelCase synthax maybe it's just enough:

```
$.blockUI({ message: $('#popup'), css: { textAlign: 'left' } });
```

Or using quotes:

```
$.blockUI({ message: $('#popup'), css: { "text-align": 'left' } });
```

Maybe you would have to force it using `!important`

```
css: { textAlign: 'left !important' }
```

Comment: or straight trough the style: .blockUI {text-align:left;}

Comment: I don't think it's that, @miro, more like `#popup{text-align:left}` as below. .blockUI is the name of the plugin itself, whereas #popup is the target.

Comment: @Doug : In [these demos](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos) it's .blockUI ... IDK. He got it to work :)

Comment: Actually you are right. Both would work because #popup would get nested inside .blockUL :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the CSS hack `!important` should do the trick. Into your CSS file add

```
#popup{
    text-align:left!important
}
```

As this should override any other CSS rules imposed upon that element (unless, of course, there are other CSS rules targeting this element also using the `!important` hack.